# Trouble integrating Blueimp Gallery with HTML & Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, blueimp

I am trying to integrate the Blueimp image gallery within a website with bootstrap and the lightbox script just doesn't start when clicking on a thumbnail. Instead, the linked image is shown in a new opened page, like it's supposed to do by default. Here is the code:

in the head goes the css:

HEAD:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/blueimp_gallery/css/blueimp-   gallery.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/blueimp_gallery/css/blueimp-gallery-indicator.css">
```

BODY:

```
  <div class="dgallery2 row">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="bg effect2">
        <div id="links">
          <a href="images/portfolio/1.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Banana">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/2.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery>
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Apple">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Orange">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Orange">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Orange">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg" title="Orange">
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Orange">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Orange">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg" title="Orange">
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Orange">
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery >
              <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Orange">
          </a>
      </div>

    <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
     <div class="slides"></div>
     <h3 class="title"></h3>
      <a class="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="next">›</a>
      <a class="close">×</a>
      <a class="play-pause"></a>
      <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    </div>    
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and then the scripts at the bottom of body:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/blueimp_gallery/js/blueimp-helper.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/blueimp_gallery/js/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/blueimp_gallery/js/blueimp-gallery-fullscreen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/blueimp_gallery/js/blueimp-gallery-indicator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/blueimp_gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
event = event || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
</script>
```

And the lightbox just won't start. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: I've searched every topic realted on blueimp gallery and done everything exactely like they did and also checked the documentation and followed every step but it doesn't show as a gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code was correct and all, only that there were some errors when loading some other Javascript scripts that I located through Error Console in the Developper panel...so I sorted those out and now blueimp works like a charm and it's responsive too :D Thanks anyway!